# Fastest way to SQL select records based on values of multiple related records in another table (one-to-many) in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given the displayed tables (simplified):

[image: Tables]

How do I in the fastest possible way select records in the main table where all related records in the "Related Table" are completed (=true) and **the latest of the "CompletedTimestamp" values** for each order is larger/smaller than a specified value?

If I wanted completed orders completed before 20/08/2013, a single record with the OrderId = 1 should be returned.

The database is MS Access, but I'm referencing it from another system using SQL and ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `HAVING` to limit you records rather than `WHERE`.

Assuming `CompletedTimestamp` is NULL where the order is not completed you can use this:

```
SELECT  m.OrderID, m.Owner, MAX(r.CompletedTimestamp) AS CompletedDate
FROM    [Main Table] m
        INNER JOIN [Related Table] r
            ON r.OrderID = m.OrderID
GROUP BY m.OrderID, m.Owner
HAVING  COUNT(r.CompletedTimeStamp) = COUNT(*)
AND     MAX(r.CompletedTimestamp) < '20130821';
```

Since `COUNT(*)` will count all records, and `COUNT(CompletedTimestamp)` will count non null CompletedTimestamps (because `COUNT(NULL)` = 0), this will only return orders where all related records are compelted.

Finally the statement `MAX(CompletedTimestamp) < '20130821'` will ensure only orders with a max completed date before the specified date are returned.